# Audio stops playing for a second

Tags: sound, video, vlc, 17.10

10` on a pentium g3258 in msi b85m-g43.When playing audio either on youtube on watching a movie(vlc or kodi) sometimes the audio stops for a second and then plays normally again.In a movie about 2 hours it happens about 10-15 times.

P.S. I noticed that the audio stops it doesn't skip seconds, I mean that it's like pausing it

Comment: Have you tried restarting the sound managers by running `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` --> Pulse audio will start itself after being killed

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/) or [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) can solve your problem

Comment: I nticed that the video stops playing after the audio pause or drops frames.I will try the methods you posted and i will come back